# Inheriting command a file lib argparser

Tags: class, python-3.x

Good afternoon
I wonder how I can inherit commands from a file that created the commands using the lib argparser.
To make it easy to understand, I will put examples:
File 1: (The house of the project may not have anything useless)

```
    import file2
    code here
```

File 2: (containing the argparser values)

```
    import argparse

    class file2():
        def function():
            argumentos = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'My Program')
            argumentos.add_argument('-command')
            argumentos_recebe = argumentos.parse_args()
```

I would like to invez to call the file 2 I called the file using one of two commands.
example:
arquivo1.py -command
Instead of ..
arquivo2.py -command
I think this is possible using class most like to find out how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import `file1` from `file1.py`, you can then refer to its contents as attributes on the `file1` module object. So, your `file1` code can be something like:

```
import file2

object = file2.file2()  # create an instance of the class
object.function()       # call the function to parse the arguments
```

Now, this won't quite work as written with the `file2` contents you showed, because your `function` method doesn't take a `self` argument. You may not actually need a class (unlike Java, you don't need to pack all of your functions into classes all the time in Python). If that's the case, you can move `function` to the top level of the module and drop the `object` parts of the my code. Then just call `file2.function()` and it will do the parsing. Note that you might want to `return` something from the function that's doing the parsing, if you need to access the results in the rest of your code in `file1`.

Comment: Ok, it worked!
Get me out more please doubts, how could I pull the values passed in the command file2 to file1?
A returne by file2 it work?
Type return (parser.parse_args.parser_argument ())
Work?

Comment: I don't actually know `argparse` very well, but in general, you can return whatever you want from the function in `file2` and use that return value in `file1` after you call the function.